# AWS CodeDeploy is not authorized to perform: codedeploy:CreateDeployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, aws-code-deploy, cicd

I'm trying to do CI/CD with aws CodeDeployand and GitHub Actions from , following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/amazon-ec2-deployment-complete-ci-cd-pipeline-using-github-actions-and-aws-codedeploy-8a477123ff7e).

but the following error appears when trying to create the deploy:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateDeployment operation: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/church-managment-bff-s3 is not authorized to perform: codedeploy:CreateDeployment on resource: arn:aws:codedeploy:sa-east-1:***:deploymentgroup:church-managment-bff/church-managment-bff-deploy-group because no identity-based policy allows the codedeploy:CreateDeployment action
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

I believe it's a permission problem, but I'm not able to solve it, can someone please help

Comment: Contact your admin to update your policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `codedeploy:CreateDeployment` permissions for `church-managment-bff-s3` user. You can do this as an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) for the user in aws console:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `aws-cli` v2, make sure you have also:

`codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig`
`codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision`

alongside

`codedeploy:CreateDeployment` .